# Solving a non-homogeneous Volterra integral equation of the second kind

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform, integral-equations

> **Q.** If $y(x)=1+\displaystyle\int_0^x e^{-(x+t)}y(t)\,dt,$ then $y(1)$ equals:
>
> (a) $0$, (b) $1$, (c) $2$, (d) $3$.

I tried the successive approximations method (starting with $y_0=0$), conversion to a DE, and finding the resolvent kernel. But none of them worked out for me! So, I thought of applying the Laplace transform technique:
\begin{align}
\mathscr{L}[y(x)]&=\mathscr{L}[1] + \mathscr{L}\left[\int_0^x e^{-(x+t)}y(t)\,dt\right]\\
&=\frac 1s + \frac 1s \mathscr{L}[e^{-(x+t)}y(t)]
\end{align}
In $\mathscr{L}[e^{-(x+t)}y(t)]$, both $x$ and $t$ are variables. Is it even possible to find $\mathscr{L}[e^{-(x+t)}y(t)]$ ?

Comment: Could you check if it is actually $e^{-(x + t)}$ inside the integral?

Comment: We have $y(0)=1.$ This implies $y>0,$ hence $y>1.$ So (a) and (b) are not possible.

Comment: @CheeHan Yes, it is. (Although it could be a misprint!)

Comment: I guess that the question should  actually read $y(x)=1+\int_0^{x} e^{-(x-t)} y(t) dt$, then one gets $y(1)=2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $y\ge 0.$ Indeed we have $y(0)=1.$ Let $x_0$ be the smallest point such that $y(x_0)=0.$ Then $y(t)>0$ for $0\le t<x_0$ and
$$0=y(x_0)=1+\int\limits_0^{x_0}e^{-(x_0+t)}y(t)\,dt >1$$
a contradiction. The positivity of $y$ implies
$y(x)>1$ for $x>0.$ Next we will show that $$y(x)<{4\over 3},\quad x\ge 0\quad (*)$$
Assume for a contradiction that $(*)$ fails. Let $x_1$ be the smallest point in $[0,1]$ such that $y(x_1)={4\over 3}.$ Then $x_1>0,$  $y(t)<{4\over 3}$ for $0\le t\le x_1$ and
$${4\over 3}=y(x_1)=1+\int\limits_0^{x_1}e^{-(x_1+t)}y(t)\,dt\le 1+{4\over 3}e^{-x_1}\int\limits_0^{x_1}e^{-t}\,dt\\
= 1+{4\over 3}e^{-x_1}(1-e^{-x_1})={4\over 3}-{1\over 3}\left (2e^{-x_1}-1\right )^2< {4\over 3}$$ a contradiction.

Summarizing we have obtained $1<y(x)<{4\over 3}$ for any $x>0.$ In particular there holds $1<y(1)<{4\over 3}.$

Comment: Wow! This shows clearly that the question was misprinted. But, still, it was a beautiful mistake. Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

Let us rewrite the integral as follows:
\begin{align*} 
\int_0^x e^{-(x + t)}y(t)\, dt = e^{-2x}\int_0^x e^{x - t}y(t)\, dt = e^{-2x}f(x). 
\end{align*}
Let $Y(s) = \mathcal{L}\{y(x)\}$. Set $g(x) = e^x$. The convolution property gives
\begin{align*} 
F(s) = \mathcal{L}\{f(x)\} = \mathcal{L}\left\{\int_0^x g(x - t)y(t)\, dt\right\} = G(s)Y(s) = \frac{1}{s - 1}Y(s). 
\end{align*}
The translation property then yields
\begin{align*} 
\mathcal{L}\left\{e^{-2x}f(x)\right\} = F(s + 2) = \frac{1}{s + 1}Y(s + 2). 
\end{align*}
Transforming the given integral equation, we get
\begin{align*} 
Y(s) & = \frac{1}{s} + \frac{1}{s + 1}Y(s + 2)\\ 
Y_{s + 2} - (s + 1)Y_s & = -\frac{s + 1}{s} = -1 - \frac{1}{s}, 
\end{align*}
which is a second-order nonhomogeneous difference equation.

Comment: Any tips for solving the last difference equation? Recursion doesn't seem helpful! Thanks...

Comment: @Usual_Learner not a clue to be honest, hence me asking whether or not it should be $e^{-(x - t)}$ instead because then we won't get a difference equation! That being said, maybe Laplace transforms is not the intended way to solve the problem.

Comment: @Usual_Learner I would probably try to expand the solution in power series or guess an ansatz, but otherwise I have no clue how to solve variable coefficient linear difference equations, not to mention it is nonhomogeneous.

Comment: I obtained $y(x) = 1 + x$ by assuming $e^{-(x-t)}$ as the kernel of the given integral equation. This results in $y(1) = 2,$ which corresponds to option (c). So, I believe it was a misprint. Otherwise, it would be too difficult to solve in a competitive exam where we hardly have a minute to answer each question. Also, for the first time, I heard the term "ansatz." Thank you... I will leave the question as it is, considering someone who loves challenges might find it interesting!

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure about the approach using Laplace Transform. However, I can suggest the following method for solving this:

First, differentiate both sides of the equation using Leibnitz rule, and note that $y(0)=1$.

So we get

$$y'(x)=x\dfrac{d}{dt}\left[e^{-(x+t)}y(t)\right]|_{t=x}=x\left[-e^{-(x+x)}y(x)+e^{-(x+x)}y'(x)\right]$$
$$\Rightarrow y'(x)= xe^{-2x}\left[y'(x)-y(x)\right]$$
$$\Rightarrow (1-xe^{-2x})y'(x)= -xe^{-2x}y(x)$$
$$\Rightarrow \dfrac{d\left(\ln y\right)}{dx}= -\dfrac{xe^{-2x}}{1-xe^{-2x}}$$

This gives $$y = \exp\left[ \int_0^x \dfrac{te^{-2t}dt}{te^{-2t}-1}\right]$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. For a function $f(x,t)$ of two variables, Leibnitz's rule gives us: $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{g(x)}^{h(x)} f(x,t)\,dt=\int_g^h \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\,dt+f(x,h(x))\cdot h'(x)-f(x,g(x))\cdot g'(x).$$ Using this, I obtained: $y'(x)+(1-e^{-2x})y(x)=1.$ However, I could not solve it! ($y'$ represents $\frac{dy}{dx}.$)

Answer (score 0):

$$y(x)=1+\displaystyle \int_0^x e^{-(x+t)}y(t)\,dt, \implies y(x)=1+e^{-x}\int_{0}^{x} e^{-t} y(t) dt $$
So $y(0)=1$,D.w.t.$x$ using Lebnitz as
$$y'(x)=-e^{-x}\int_{0}^{x} e^{-t} y(t) dt+e^{-x} e^{-x} y(x).$$
$$\implies y'(x)=-(y-1)+e^{-2x} y(x)$$
$$\implies y'(x)+(1-e^{-2x})y(x)=1$$
This is liner ODE whose integrating factor is $$I=e^{\int (x-e^{-2x})dx}=e^{x+\frac{1}{2}e^{-2x}}.$$
So,
$$y(x)=e^{-x-\frac{1}{2}e^{-2x}}\int e^{x+\frac{1}{2}e^{-2x}} dx+ C e^{-x-\frac{1}{2}e^{-2x}}$$
$$y(x)=1-\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-x-\frac{1}{2}e^{-2x}} \text{Erfi}(e^{-x}/\sqrt{2})+C e^{-x-\frac{1}{2}e^{-2x}}$$

Note that $\int e^{x+\frac{1}{2}e^{-2x}} dx=e^{x+\frac{1}{2}e^{-2x}}-\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \text{Erfi}(e^{-x}/\sqrt{2}).$

Comment: Honestly, I know nothing about the function you mentioned at the end. Does this expression for $y(x)$ result in $y(1)$ being $2$ or $3$? Thanks...

Comment: Even I did not like the final answer. In fact the solution of $y(x)=1+\int_{0}^{x} e^{-(x-t)} y(t) dt$, will give $y(1)=2$. So please double check if it is $e^{x+t}$ or $e^{x-t}$ in the question

Comment: It could be a misprint. Unfortunately, I have no way to verify.